# Hide/Block System Preference Panes?

Tags: macos, security, system-settings

I have just discovered that System Preference panes such as Mouse and Keyboard cannot be locked, this is a problem as one user could log in change the strings and then another user would log in and could become confused as to why they have changed.

Is there anyway of blocking or locking these preference panes? I need access to them as an administrator but I want all other users not to have access just like any other preference pane.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the Mouse and Keyboard preference panes are per-user settings: if one user logs in and changes settings, a different user's login shouldn't be affected.

If you still want to disable the preference panes, check out [Diablotin](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Diablotin.html). You can use that to disable preference panes (among other things) and it can be locked with a password.

Comment: This is of course assuming you have a separate user account for each user -- that everyone is not logging into the same account. That is the best way to do it (as opposed to using one account and trying to lock down different pieces)